# What option do I have to set to remove the mesh from the cylinder?

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[viewpoint=5 30 45 rtp2xyz,Decran=5](-6,-6)(6,6)
    \psSolid[object=cylindrecreux,h=2,r=1,fillcolor=cyan,ngrid=30 30]
    \axesIIID(1,1,1)(3,3,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What option do I have to set to remove the mesh from the cylinder such that the cylinder looks clean, smooth with gradient color?

### Edit:

When I set `linewidth=0` I got the following, but I am not sure that `linewidth=0` is the recommended solution.

[image]

Comment: `linestyle=none` doesn't work.

Comment: @Werner: Yes. I have tried it before.

Comment: Just as an aside: I find the cylinder without mesh looks too plain... Maybe keep the mesh, but with thin, almost completely transparent lines?

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Keeping the circular edges can reduce the plainness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[viewpoint=30 30 20 rtp2xyz,Decran=30,lightsrc=viewpoint](-6,-6)(6,6)
    \psSolid[object=cylindrecreux,h=2,r=1,fillcolor=cyan,ngrid=20 20,
             grid=false]
    \axesIIID(1,1,2)(3,3,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that this does not work when the option `opacity` is used for transparency.

Comment: `action=draw*` but then you can not have invisible lines and areas.

Comment: actually mixing `action=draw*` with `grid=false` makes the strangest behavior: only hidden grid lines are shown (but dashed).